# Eagerly Disposing a ManualResetEvent

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I have a class which allows other threads to wait until it finishes an operation using a `ManualResetEventSlim`.  (The operations are typically brief)

This class has no explicit lifetime, so there is no single place that I can easily close the event.
Instead, I want to close the event as soon as it's finished with—as soon as it's signalled, and after any waiting threads wake up.

For performance reasons, I'd prefer not to use a lock.

Is this code thread-safe, and can it be made faster?

```
volatile bool isCompleted;
volatile int waitingCount;
ManualResetEventSlim waiter = new ManualResetEventSlim();

//This method is called on any thread other than the one that calls OnCompleted
public void WaitForCompletion() {
    if (isCompleted)
        return;

    Interlocked.Increment(ref waitingCount);
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    if (!isCompleted)
        waiter.Wait();

    if (0 == Interlocked.Decrement(ref waitingCount)) {
        waiter.Dispose();
        waiter = null;
    }
    return;
}

//This method is called exactly once.
protected internal virtual void OnCompleted(string result) {
    Result = result;
    isCompleted = true;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    if (waitingCount == 0) {
        waiter.Dispose();
        waiter = null;
    } else
        waiter.Set();
}
```

Comment: Looking at it further, I think it might double-dispose the waiter if both methods are called at the same time.

Comment: Calling `Dispose` more than once is safe with all compliant `IDisposable` implementations.

Comment: @six: True, but I'm also `null`ing the variable.  However, that might not be necessary.

Comment: @SLaks: I would avoid the `null`ing, I've found it does not help and ends up at some point introducing a weird corner case.

Comment: Also, `ManualResetEventSlim.Dispose` is not threadsafe; It's probably not OK to call it twice _at once_.

Comment: @SLaks: I'm looking at it right now and it appears to be threadsafe. It locks on the internal event object before closing it.

Comment: Yes; I just saw that.  The comments say it isn't, but the code says it is.

Comment: @six: I've decided to follow your advice.  Put that into an answer and I'll accept it.  Do you have any other suggestions about the code?

Comment: @SLaks: it is my understanding that to be compliant, `Dispose` must be very tolerant. MS guidelines: "To help ensure that resources are always cleaned up appropriately, a Dispose method should be callable multiple times without throwing an exception." I take that to mean it should be tolerant of multiple threads calling it as well. I've toyed around with some sample code for your problem, but I've not come up with any real improvements.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think the spec demands that `Dispose` be thread-safe, and I certainly wouldn't assume that any `Dispose()` call is threadsafe.  For example, most native resources (eg, GDI+ or window handles) are not threadsafe.

Comment: I agree in the case of GDI+/Window Handles, which have certain threading requirements. But I think any usages of those should move to `SafeHandle`s to acknowledge their critical finalization requirements (if you have any). As for a synchronization construct like `ManualResetEventSlim`, it seems crazy that it wouldn't support free-threaded disposing. By definition it will be used in a multi-threaded environment. But, as you note assumptions can be bad :)

Comment: I would agree to remove the assignment to null. Because of that assignment, it looks like you could also get a null reference calling waiter.Set() if both calls are in a position to potentially dispose, but the OnCompleted call sees someone waiting and the WaitForCompletion call disposes it and nulls the reference before the OnCompleted actually reaches the Set().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest thing I see with your code is the setting of the `waiter` to `null` after calling `Dispose`. I have a large body of managed wrappers over unmanaged interfaces that I am in charge of and when I moved to .Net 4.0 this practice came back to bite me in some threading scenarios.

The MSDN information on `ManualResetEventSlim.Dispose` suggests that it is not threadsafe, however, looking over its actual implementation there is nothing dangerous about multiple invocations of `Dispose` from multiple threads. Additionally, implementations of `IDisposable` are supposed to be *very* tolerant of multiple invocations (as specified in their design guidance).

<strike>One idea I'd toyed with would reorder `OnCompleted` slightly to allow a reader if it subscribes shortly after it completes:</strike>

```
//This method is called exactly once.
protected internal virtual void OnCompleted(string result) {
    Result = result;
    isCompleted = true;

    waiter.Set();
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    if (waitingCount == 0) {
        waiter.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: A reader cannot subscribe shortly after it completes.  If `waitingCount` is already zero, any waiters will see that `isCompleted` is `true` before calling `Wait()`.

Comment: @SLaks: Things got a little messy on my paper where I was working this out :) I've stricken that from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Worse, there are conditions under which it won't dispose of the waiter at all. If you call `OnCompleted` when `waitingCount > 0`, the `isCompleted` flag will get set to `true`, but the waiter won't be disposed. When something calls `WaitForCompletion`, it will see that `isCompleted` is `true`, and exit immediately. `waiter.Dispose` never gets called.</strike>

Why not use something like [SpinLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock.aspx), which uses the same kind of logic as `ManualResetEventSlim`? If your waits are typically very short, then the lock probably won't be contended and it's a huge win. If the wait is long, then the `ManualResetEventSlim` was going to pay the price of the kernel transition anyway.

Are you so certain that using a lock would be prohibitively expensive? There's "knowing," and then there's measuring . . .

Comment: No, I'm not certain; I'd just like to avoid one if possible.

Comment: I was already considering using `SpinLock`; I just asked the question to see if there are any clever alternatives.

Comment: Upon further study, I'm not sure that my statement above is true. That is, it might not be possible to leave the waiter un-disposed. But you're right that there is a race condition that could result in a double dispose.

Comment: I don't think your first point is correct.  If `waitingCount > 0`, the last Wait call to finish will dispose the waiter.