# Synchronization across threads / atomic checks?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization, atomic

I need to create an method invoker that any thread (Thread B for example sake) can call, which will execute on the main executing thread (Thead A) at a specific given point in its execution.

Example usage would be as follows:

```
static Invoker Invoker = new Invoker();

static void ThreadA()
{
    new Thread(ThreadB).Start();

    Thread.Sleep(...); // Hypothetic Alpha

    Invoker.Invoke(delegate { Console.WriteLine("Action"); }, true);

    Console.WriteLine("Done");

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void ThreadB()
{
    Thread.Sleep(...); // Hypothetic Beta

    Invoker.Execute();
}
```

The Invoker class looks like this:

```
public class Invoker
{
    private Queue<Action> Actions { get; set; }

    public Invoker()
    {
        this.Actions = new Queue<Action>();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        while (this.Actions.Count > 0)
        {
            this.Actions.Dequeue()();
        }
    }

    public void Invoke(Action action, bool block = true)
    {
        ManualResetEvent done = new ManualResetEvent(!block);

        this.Actions.Enqueue(delegate
        {
            action();
            if (block) done.Set();
        });

        if (block)
        {
            done.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine in most cases, although it won't if, for any reason, the execution (and therefore the `Set`) is done before the `WaitOne`, in which case it will just freeze (it allows for the thread to proceed, then blocks). That could be reproduced if Alpha >> Beta.

I can use booleans and whatnot, but I'm never getting a real atomic safety here. I tried some fixes, but they wouldn't work in the case where Beta >> Alpha.

I also thought of locking around both the Invoker.Execute and Invoker.Invoke methods so that we are guaranteed that the execution does not occur between enqueing and waiting. However, the problem is that the lock also englobes the WaitOne, and therefore never finishes (deadlock).

How should I go about getting absolute atomic safety in this paradigm?

Note: It really is a requirement that I work with this design, from external dependencies. So changing design is not a real option.

**EDIT**: I did forget to mention that I want a blocking behaviour (based on `bool block`) until the delegate is executed on the Invoke call.

Comment: Don't create a `ManualResetEvent` if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Semaphore(Slim)` instead of the `ManualResetEvent`.

Create a semaphore with an maximum count of `1`, call `WaitOne()` in the calling thread, and call `Release()` in the delegate.

If you've already called `Release()`, `WaitOne()` should return immediately.

Make sure to `Dispose()` it when you're done, preferably in a `using` block.
If `block` is false, you shouldn't create it in the first place (although for `SemaphoreSlim`, that's not so bad).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Testing right now. Did you mean `SemaphoreSlim` and `Wait()` instead of `Semaphore(Slim)` and `WaitOne()`?

Comment: Also, where can I call `Dispose` to make sure it only gets called once and at the right time? Actually, I can easily place it in the delegate, but then I might be accessing a disposed object on `Wait` if the execution occured before the wait.

Comment: I asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266597/eagerly-disposing-a-manualresetevent).

Comment: So basically the answer to take the rick of disposing twice? I tried that, and I get an error caused by AlreadyDisposedException.

Comment: My case is somewhat different; that answer won't help you.  (I know that neither thread will use it again; you don't)

Comment: @SLaks let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1545/discussion-between-lazlo-bonin-and-slaks)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [my technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266597/eagerly-disposing-a-manualresetevent):

```
public void BlockingInvoke(Action action)
{
    volatile bool isCompleted = false;
    volatile bool isWaiting = false;
    ManualResetEventSlim waiter = new ManualResetEventSlim();

    this.Actions.Enqueue(delegate
    {
        action();

        isCompleted = true;
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        if (!isWaiting) 
            waiter.Dispose();
        else
            waiter.Set();
    });

    isWaiting = true;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    if (!isCompleted)
        waiter.Wait();
    waiter.Dispose();
}
```

*Untested*

Comment: The major problem I see with this is that ifs are not atomic. The value of `isCompleted` and `isWaiting` could change between your if and the action.

Comment: @Lazlo: That's what the memory barriers are for.  They're not atomic, but they are sequential.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that this is fully thread-safe.  If it finishes inside `if (isCompleted)` then `isWaiting` will be `true` and it will set the event.

Comment: If it starts waiting inside `if (!isWaiting)` then `isCompleted` will be true and it won't call `Wait()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering only to show the implementation SLaks described and my solution to ensure proper and unique disposal with locks. It's open to improvement and criticism, but it actually works.

```
public class Invoker
{
    private Queue<Action> Actions { get; set; }

    public Invoker()
    {
        this.Actions = new Queue<Action>();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        while (this.Actions.Count > 0)
        {
            this.Actions.Dequeue()();
        }
    }

    public void Invoke(Action action, bool block = true)
    {
        if (block)
        {
            SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
            bool disposed = false;

            this.Actions.Enqueue(delegate
            {
                action();
                semaphore.Release();

                lock (semaphore)
                {
                    semaphore.Dispose();
                    disposed = true;
                }
            });

            lock (semaphore)
            {
                if (!disposed)
                {
                    semaphore.Wait();
                    semaphore.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.Actions.Enqueue(action);
        }
    }
}
```